# Related Posts with Numbers Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to add numbers in posts to get the output below:

[image]

```
 <?php 
                        $args= array(
                            'posts_per_page'=>8,
                            'date_query' => array(
                                array(
        'year' => date( 'Y' ),
        'week' => date( 'W' ),
    ),
),
                            'meta_key' => 'popular_posts',
                            'order' => 'DESC',
                            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'

                            );
                            $i=0;
                            $funLoop = new WP_Query( $args );
                            while ($funLoop -> have_posts() ) : $funLoop->the_post(); $i++;
                            $cat = get_the_category($post->ID)[0];
                        ?>
```

```html
<div class="small-12 medium-6 columns unpadded">
<article class="small-12 med columns articles-<?php echo$cat->slug; ?>">
<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
<div class="number">
1.
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand what you want to realize.

Comment: Mike, just want to add numbers to every post 1,2,3 etc look at the screenshot. Example: https://ibb.co/ebCU5p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method is to wrap your content in `<ol>`. But if you cant you can make usage of the css counter.

Example:
Your html:

```
<div class="small-12 medium-6 columns unpadded">
<article class="small-12 med columns articles-<?php echo$cat->slug; ?>">
<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
<div class="number">

</div>
</a>
<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
<div class="number">

</div>
</a>
<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
<div class="number">

</div>
</a>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
      counter-reset: mynum;
    }

    .artikulli a .number {
      counter-increment: mynum;
    }
   .artikulli a .number:before {
      content: counter(mynum)".";
    }
```

Working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBgKrW

Comment: Hi dear full code: http://txt.do/dz8sb i need php code to see it completely I have all day to deal with this :)

Comment: i have edited my answer according to your txt. Just add the CSS part to your css.